# Trouble replacing radio buttons with a dropdown in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have code that's something this below, 
it has some controls on it [some radios and a dropdown] I want to replace the radios.

both the radio buttons and the dropdown populate. I want to replace the radios. but the change function takes a region parameter -- it works for the radios but not for the dropdown. I cannot figure out how its getting passed in for the radio buttons [but it is]. and it does not get passed in for the dropdown. WHY??? :-(

```
var dropDown = d3.select("#custs")
        .append("div")
        .append("select")
        .attr("name", "cust-list");



  var regionsByFruit = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) { return d.fruit; })
                .entries(data)
                .reverse();

  var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
                .data(regionsByFruit)
                .enter()
                .append("option");


  options.append("option")
                .attr("name", "fruit")
                .attr("value", function (d) { return d.key; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.key })

                .filter(function (d, i) { return !i; });

   dropDown.on("change", change);

   //radio buttons
   var label = d3.select("#custs").selectAll("label")
               .data(regionsByFruit)
               .enter()
              .append("div").append("label");

   label.append("input")
                .attr("type", "radio")
                .attr("name", "fruit")
                .attr("value", function (d) { return d.key; })
                .on("change", change)
                .filter(function (d, i) { return !i; })
                .each(change)
                .property("checked", true);

    // adds the labels to the radio buttons
    label.append("span")
                .text(function (d) { return d.key; });


     function change(region) {
                var data0 = path.data(),
                    data1 = pie(region.values);




                var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - 40)
                    .innerRadius(radius - 40);


                path = path.data(data1, key);
                text = text.data(data1, key);


                path.enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .each(function (d, i) { this._current = findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) || d; })
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.ID })
                    .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.region); })
                    .append("svg:title")
                    .text(function (d, i) { return "Account: " + d.data.region; });
                //.on("mouseover", function (d) { tip.show(d, document.getElementById(d.ID)) })
                //.on('mouseout', tip.hide);


                text.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("stroke", "white")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function (d, i) {
                        return d.data.count;
                        console.log("CNT " + d.data.count)
                    });

                path.exit()
                    .datum(function (d, i) { return findNeighborArc(i, data1, data0, key) || d; })
                  .transition()
                    .duration(750)
                    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
                    .remove();

                path.transition()
                    .duration(750)
                    .attrTween("d", arcTween);


            }
        });
    }

    function key(d) {
        return d.data.region;
    }
```

Comment: It would helpful if you could format your code in a more readable way, and also isolate the portion that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Instead of `dropDown.on("change", change);` try `options.on("change", change);`.

Comment: Is the select element structured properly? You're appending option elements twice. Also, I found I had to get the value from the select myself in the change event, it's not passed in.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting [I thought it was ok.] pretty new to d3 though.  I tried changing the code to options.on("cange", change) and if I do that the event does not fire.

Comment: The main issue I have is that the option buttons are in fact passing the region parameter in [and I don't know how] The drop down does not pass the parameter in; so it is undefined.  If someone could indicate to me HOW the radio buttons are able to pass in the region parameter I could fix the dropdown. I do not know the portion that is giving me trouble.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5682158

Comment: This is the basic code I started with in the link above. It does not have the issue i describe since it does not have a drop down; but it was my starting point.